# How can I highlight Java bytecode?

Tags: highlighting, minted, java

I usually use minted to display highlighted source code. But it seems as if minted would not support Java bytecode (see [list of supported languages](http://martin-thoma.com/how-to-print-source-code-with-latex/#Supported_Languages-2)).

How can I insert highlighted [java bytecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode)?

(Is there perhaps another "language" that has a similar instruction set? Does listings have an option for bytecode? Has somebody manually created a highlighting file for minted/listings?)

Comment: Creating a style using `listings` is easier than writing a new lexer for `pygments`. It is a matter of adding the appropriate keywords on different lists: `\keywords=[1]{iconst,iload,iconst}`, `\keywords[2]={goto,return}`, etc... Each keyword type can be highlighted differently using `keywordstyle=[1]{\color{blue}}` and so on.

Comment: I know this question is old, but if it still stand, could you specify the type of syntax highlighting you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

Since, AFAICS, no one has done this already, you need to write a JVM lexer for Pygments.  That involves some not quite trivial Python programming: see [the official instructions](http://pygments.org/docs/lexerdevelopment/) for several approaches to constructing a lexer, but you will likely find that the RegexLexer suffices for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

It has been possible to highlight JVM bytecode since v1.3 of listings using the language name of `JVMIS` (Java Virtual Machine Instruction Set, I believe). It's actually mentioned on that page you linked in the OP.

Comment: Are you certain that this was true when this question was asked? Your answer strongly suggests that the OP has simply not bothered to read the information on the linked page. If that's the case, fair enough. But, if the support you mention is actually newer than the question, then might I recommend a slightly less scathing tone?

Comment: @cfr I re-read my answer and I honestly don't think it qualifies as "scathing." It was intended to be a casual tone, if anything. `JVMIS` is not a very intuitive keyword when one wants to highlight JVM bytecode, so I established the link for OP.

This has been supported since v1.3c (05/2006): [take a look at page 2](https://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/iui.inst.200/files/staff/domaschka/misc/tex_listings-13.pdf).

Having come across this question earlier today, before I found my answer, I thought I would come back and post it for future readers of this question.

Comment: In that case, it certainly pre-dates the question!

Comment: The mentioned page tells that `listings` package can display `JVMIS`, but OP asked about `minted` package. Both are mentioned there, but I wouldn't call them drop-in replacements for one another.